# WebSphere MQ DISC vs KAINT on SVRCONN channels

Tags: ibm-mq, channel, keep-alive

we have a major problem with many of our Applications making improper connections (SVRCONN) with queue manager and not issuing MQDISC when connection not required. This causes lot of idle stale connections and prevents Application from making new connections and fails with CONNECTION BROKEN (2009) error. We have been restricting Application connections with clientidle parameter in our Windows MQ on version 7.0.1.8 but when we migrated to MQ v7.5.0.2 in Linux platform we are deciding on the best option available in the new version. We do not have clientidle anymore in ini file for v7.5 but has DISCINT & KAINT in SVRCONN channels. I have been going through the advantages and disadvantages of both for our scenario of Application making connections through SVRCONN channels and leave connections open without issuing a disconnect. Which of these above channel attributes is ideal for us. Any suggestions? Does any of these take precedence over the other??

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First off, `KAINT` controls TCP functions, not MQ functions.  That means for it to take effect, the TCP `Keepalive` function must be enabled in the `qm.ini` TCP stanza.  Nothing wrong with this, but the native `HBINT` and `DISCINT` are more responsive than delegating to TCP.  This addresses the problem that the OS hasn't recognized that a socket's remote partner is gone and cleaned up the socket.  As long as the socket exists and MQ's channel is idle, MQ won't notice.  When TCP cleans the socket up, MQ's exception callback routine sees it immediately and closes the channel.

Of the remaining two, `DISCINT` controls the interval after which MQ will terminate an idle but *active* socket whereas `HBINT` controls the interval after which MQ will shut down an MCA attached to an *orphan* socket.  Ideally, you will have a modern MQ client and server so you can use both of these.

The `DISCINT` should be a value longer than the longest expected interval between messages if you want the channel to stay up during the Production shift.  So if a channel should have message traffic at least once every 5 minutes by design, then a `DISCINT` longer than 5 minutes would be required to avoid channel restart time.

The `HBINT` actually flows a small heartbeat message over the channel, but only will do so if `HBINT` seconds have passed without a message.  Thsi catches the case that the socket is dead but TCP hasn't yet cleaned it up.  `HBINT` allows MQ to discover this before the OS and take care of it, including tearing down the socket.

In general, really low values for `HBINT` can cause lots of unnecessary traffic.  For example, `HBINT(5)` would flow a heartbeat every five second interval in which no other channel traffic is passed.  chances are, you don't need to terminate orphan channels within 5 seconds of the loss of the socket so a larger value is perhaps more useful.  That said, `HBINT(5)` would cause zero extra traffic in a system with a sustained message rate of 1/second - until the app died, in which case the orphan socket would be killed pretty quick.

For more detail, please go to the [SupportPacs page](http://ibm.co/SupptPacs) and look for the Morag's "Keeping Channels Running" presentation.

Comment: Great answer. Only thing I would add is to note that although you don't have ClientIdle in the ini file anymore, DISCINT on a SVRCONN is exactly the same function but now configured on a per channel basis, so if you want exactly what you had before, that is the equivalent setting.